# Bitrise Google Play Deploy: Issue with input: No JSONKeyPath nor P12KeyPath provided

Tags: android, bitrise

Have recently moved over to Bitrise.io now that BuddyBuild is dropping support for Android. I've added `Google Play Deploy` to my Bitrise workflow but I'm trying to figure out how to add my Service Account JSON to Bitrise.

On the `Workflow Editor` it asks:

```
For remote JSON key file you can provide any download location (ex: https://URL/TO/key.json). For local JSON key file provide file path url. (ex: file://PATH/TO/key.json).`
```

I don't really want to host the JSON file publicly so the first is not an option. I went to the `Code Signing` tab on the `Workflow Editor` and uploaded my JSON file and it gave me an environment variable (`$BITRISEIO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL`). When editing the `Service Account JSON key file path` for `Google Play Deploy` and putting in the environment variable the `Google Play Deploy` step fails:

`Issue with input: No JSONKeyPath nor P12KeyPath provided`

What am I doing wrong? I'm assuming I can't pass in environment variables into the `Service Account JSON key file path`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Viktor, CTO of https://www.bitrise.io

It seems this issue was most likely related to a recent faulty deploy which affected files uploaded after the deploy.

The issue is fixed now, if you'd have still see this happen please contact our support!

Related issue report / discussion: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/file-downloader-failed-to-download-keystore-cannot-find-source-url/3709/2

We're terribly sorry for the inconvenience, we'll do everything we can to prevent a similar issue to happen in the future.

---

If you'd still experience the issue please contact our support via the onsite chat as we'll need the URL of the build to be able to check its configs/full logs.